# Pip install: ERROR: failed building wheel for wordcloud

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install a package via pip, howver it keeps exiting with

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1`

then a bunch of running/creating/copying/building in red then:

`ERROR: Failed building wheel for word`

basicallly it fails to build and install the package and I cannot for the life of my figure out why.

Comment: please, show the commands you are using..

Comment: Add `--with-debug` to your install command and paste the output to your question.

Comment: The _bunch of running/creating/copying/building in red_ is the crucial part - please add it to the question.